# Need a help to solve an SQL Server Query regarding a Date Time condition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Please can anyone help/suggest me to solve the following condition which is inside one of my SELECT queries

```
  ExamDate >= CONVERT(date, getdate()) 
AND ExamEndTime >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)
```

Where I need to check the second condition when only the ExamDate is equal to getdate(), if ExamDate is > than getdate() I need to ignore the second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ExamDate > CONVERT(date, getdate()) 
or (ExamDate = CONVERT(date, getdate()) AND ExamEndTime >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **DateDiff** when compairing date objects

```
DATEDIFF(day,ExamDate, getdate()) >= 0
OR (DATEDIFF(hh,ExamEndTime,GETDATE()) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(day,ExamDate, getdate())=0)
```